# autoit script to click on random links on a website?

Tags: html, autoit

This is my script:

```
Local $oIE = _IECreate("www.google.com")
For $i = 1 To 25 Step 1
_IENavigate($oIE, "http://mysite.us")
    _IELinkClickByText($oIE, "link" & Random(1, 25, 1))
    Sleep(100)
    Next
_IEQuit($oIE)
```

What my script does is open `mysite.us` and click on random links 1 to 25. After clicking 25 links randomly, it closes IE. But I want it to click 1 to any number of links that I put in my site. Right now, only 25 links are there. In future, if I put more links and more links, it will continue to click those too.

I don't want to edit script each time I put links on my site. So,is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hmmm. What's the purpose of this script? It seems a bit nefarious.

Comment: I will host lots of flash games...put all those flash games links in one place....autoit will open one game link for 15 minutes..then go back to the place again and will pick up another game link for 15 minutes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)
Local $iNumLinks = @extended
_IELinkClickByIndex($oIE, Random(0, $iNumLinks))
```